# ASP.NET Core 3: response 404 during integration test produced by RedirectResult("MyList")

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, integration-testing, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.0

I have two pages `/MyArea/Pages/Create.cshtml` and `/MyArea/Pages/MyList.cshtml`. So I create an entity and finish it with `return RedirectResult("MyList")`.

This works in browser.

But during the integration test (using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing` package ver 3.0) when I open the `/MyArea/Create` page and POST the form:

```
 var createConfirmHttpResponseMessage = await httpClient.SendAsync(postRequest1);
 Assert.IsTrue(createConfirmHttpResponseMessage.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK);
```

All this returns

> {StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:{  Content-Length: 0}}

Entity was created and `return RedirectResult("MyList")` was called

Request message reported: `{Method: GET, RequestUri: 'http://localhost/MyList', Version: 1.1, Content: <null>, Headers: {  Cookie: .AspNetCore.Antiforgery....  Cookie: .AspNetCore.Antiforgery....}}`

I see that request's message is incorrect: RequestUri should contain an area //localhost/**MyArea**/MyList,

What kind of "current location management" I should add to the integration test code to force httpClient "respect" the area?

P.S. I could write it this way `return RedirectResult("/MyArea/MyList")` on server side but now I want to know how to repeat browser's behavior in the integration test?

Answer (score 0):

One option that I have found so far is to set `clientOptions.AllowAutoRedirect=false` and then process redirects manually. It is strange that HttpClient doesn't "respect" current location during the automated redirect. It seems like a bug of `HttpClient`.